# Is it possible to Show FPS debug information in 3D-View like in BGE?

Tags: game-engine, interface, 3d-view, light

I have a simple scene with multiply lights that i want to view in Viewport texturing: 'Material' mode.

with this the Blender-UI gets slowed down drastically with some blend-files/setups. i like to know what is causing this - in the Blender Game Engine (BGE) there is a option to show 'Framerate and Profile' information:
[image]

**is it possible to show same/similar information for/in normal 3D-View?**

Comment: As far as I know there is no profiler on the Blender Preview window. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes just use:
`bge.logic.getAverageFrameRate()`